# Count all rows and add a certain int from column of each result row into overall count

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table consisting of columns tblEventID, isSafeSlot, plusOnes. I want to retrieve the number of rows where tblEventID is equal to `X` and isSafeSlot is equal to `true`, and if both are true, also check the column `plusOnes` for that one row. This column will hold an int from 0 to 99. I need to add those numbers also into the count.

So say we have this table:

```
tblEventID / isSafeSlot / plusOnes
100 / true / 0
100 / true / 53
100 / false / 0 
101 / true / 99
```

And I am giving it tblEventID 100, the count result should be 55 (two rows making the count 2, plus one row has the number 53 stored under `plusOnes`, result 55)

How can I make this inside one query?

Comment: Please post your current code and describe what is the issue with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) + SUM(plusOnes) AS total
FROM `say_we_have_this_table`
WHERE tblEventId = 100
 AND isSafeSlot = true;
```

Comment: that is totally correct. thank yoU!

Answer (score 2):

Filter the rows of the table with your conditions and aggregate:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) + SUM(plusOnes)
FROM tablename
WHERE tblEventID = 100 AND isSafeSlot;
```

or, simpler:

```
SELECT SUM(plusOnes + 1)
FROM tablename
WHERE tblEventID = 100 AND isSafeSlot;
```